# What is stopping us from deleting a UILabel inside a UITableViewCell from the storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

After creating a `UILabel` programmatically to be added to a `UITableViewCell`, I'm unable to delete the label object from the storyboard. Usually by clicking on the object in the document outline we're able to delete it. However when attempting to delete the unneeded `UILabel` in the storyboard, it won't go away.  Has anyone else experienced this? How did you delete the object form the storyboard?

[image]

Comment: It might be a xcode bug.try restarting xcode

Comment: Is it worked :@laurence

Comment: @RohitPradhan restarting xcode was a good idea however the bug was our problem as we had the Table View Cell object in storyboard set to "subtitle" in the attributes.  Once we changed the style to "custom" in attributes, it removed the title and detail UILabels.  Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Nice answer by aaron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot delete labels from table view cells that have a predefined style. To fully customize the cell's appearance, select Custom style:

[image]

This change will remove the labels.

Comment: Once we changed the style to "custom" in attributes, it removed the title and detail UILabels that we thought were objects set by us initially in storyboard.  Thank you for this answer